# What is the difference between same products in google.apis and google.cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, dialogflow-es

So, I was going to try out connecting dialogflow with my app using c#, when I noticed that there were 2 dialogflow products -

Google.Apis.Dialogflow
         and
Google.Cloud.Dialogflow

I'm pretty sure that I'm supposed to be using Google.Cloud, but just out of curiosity, what are the differences between the 2 packages? Is google.apis offline?

I've tried searching it up, and the only vague answer I found was here -
[link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866009/whether-to-use-googleapis-or-google-cloud-library-for-node-js)

Even though it does explain the difference between the two, it doesn't explain why would both google.apis and google.cloud would have the same service.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [page](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained) after searching a bit which explains the differences.  Basically `google.cloud` is the recommended one to use when you are able to, but it does not yet support all languages and libraries.

`google.apis` is older and generated automatically

`google.cloud` is mostly created by hand and the newer version

This [link](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries) contains some useful reference material for the cloud library.

Comment: Oh. So as the page says, cloud is basically the newer one, and apis is the more stable older one. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Pranav Badrinathan Yeah thats what it appears to me, basically use `cloud` if you can.